# React-Native place multiple markers in a map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-markers, react-native

The function below retrieves coordinates from an api and pushes the coordinates in an array.

```
function getMarkers() {

  fetch('http://xxxxxx').then(function(response) { 
  // Convert to JSON
  return response.json();
   }).then(function(j) {

  var number = j.Objects.length;
  var markers = [];

  for(var x = 0; x < number; x++) {
     markers.push("{latlng: {latitude: \""+j.Objects[0].WGS84_Y+"\", longitude: \""+j.Objects[0].WGS84_X+"}, title:\""+x+"\", description:\"2\"}, key:\""+x+" },");
  }

  return(markers);
  });
}
```

The class below should retrieve the markers coming from the function above.

```
 class Home extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    const markers = getMarkers();
    this.state = {markers:[{markers}]}
 } ....
```

This doesn't work. I get the error: "undefined is not an object(evaluating this.state.markers.map"

It only works when I place the array manually in the constructor, like this:

```
  this.state = {markers:[ 
            {latlng: {latitude: 52.786894, longitude: 6.118069}, title: "vic", description: "voc",key:"0"}
            {latlng: {latitude: 52.796894, longitude: 6.178069}, title: "vic", description: "voc",key:"1"} ]}
```

};

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your first function is called `getMarkers` but your home class call `getMark()`. Also `getMarkers` does an AJAX request which mean when it return `markers` it return an empty array as the return will be executed before the AJAX call is returned.

Comment: Yes the **getMark** was a typo, but not the main problem. 
I still get the full array from the getMarkers function when I do a `return(alert(markers))` and call the function in `onRegionChange ={getMarkers}`. It shows the array in a alert.

Comment: It looks indeed that in the construct that getMarkers() is empty. I am a bit lost now. Is there a way to return the array with the AJAX results after the AJAX call is returned?